# how do i print a "get" methods return value to console

Tags: java, console

hello im just trying out some basic java skills.

here is my code

```
package bankaccount;
public class Test {

    String name;
    int houseno;
    int balance;

    Test (String n,int h,int b) {

        n=name;
        h=houseno;
        b=balance;

    }
   int getBalance(){   

    return balance;
}
   void setBalance(int newBalance){

       newBalance = balance;
   }

}

//the class containing my main

package bankaccount;

/**
 *
 * @author ideapc
 */
public class BankAccount {
Test t1 = new Test("tim",147,5);
    System.out.println(t1.getBalance() + "name =");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

I am trying to print the balance of the object t1 (tim) to the console using system.out.println

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `System.out.println()` inside your `main()` method.

```
 public class BankAccount {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test t1 = new Test("tim",147,5);
      System.out.println("name = "+t1.getBalance());
     }  
 }
```

You need to change your constructor of `Test` too.

```
Test (String n,int h,int b) {
     this.name=n;
     this.houseno=h;
     this.balance=b;
}
```

Comment: is saying in the console that balance =0 rather than 5?

Comment: @user3462534 yes. change your constructor as here in `Test`. Then you will get the expected result.